# Get IPs as string/list in Terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, tuples, user-data

I'm beginning by creating a few machines:

```
resource "aws_instance" "servers" {
  count = 20
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  ...........................
}
```

and then, I want to create a "master machine", like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "master" {
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  .................................
  user_data = <<-EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    yum -y install python-pip
    mkdir /ansible
    cd /ansible
    touch inventory
    echo "${aws_instance.servers[*].public_ip}" > inventory
    echo "server_hostname" >> inventory
    pip install ansible
  EOF
}
```

Basically I want the IPs of the machines to be in my Ansible inventory on the master machine. My issue however is that when I try to apply the terraform, I run into this:

```
aws_instance.servers is tuple with 2 elements
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

How can I solve this?

Tried to get a list of the IPs of some EC2 machines in order to have it in a file on a master EC2, via user_data script. However, the issue is that I can't convert it from tuple.

Comment: You are creating `resource "aws_instance" "servers"`, but you are not using it at all. Thus your error is not related to that code you provided. Instead you have `aws_instance.instances[*].public_ip` which is different and not explained in your question.

Comment: Just saw now, sorry for the confusion, but I copied the wrong block(I have a few versions and somehow got the wrong one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have more than one IP address to include, you will need to explain to Terraform how you want to format those multiple IP addresses into a single string to include into the template result.

For example, you could tell Terraform to produce a space-separated sequence of IP addresses:

```
resource "aws_instance" "master" {
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  .................................
  user_data = <<-EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    yum -y install python-pip
    mkdir /ansible
    cd /ansible
    touch inventory
    echo "${join(" ", aws_instance.servers[*].public_ip)}" > inventory
    echo "server_hostname" >> inventory
    pip install ansible
  EOF
}
```

This example uses [the `join` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/join) to concatenate the IP addresses together with spaces.

If you need something more specialized and would benefit from writing an entire template block per element then you can alternatively use [template directives](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#directives). For example, if you want to run a separate command for each IP address:

```
resource "aws_instance" "master" {
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  .................................
  user_data = <<-EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    yum -y install python-pip
    mkdir /ansible
    cd /ansible
    touch inventory
    %{ for ip in aws_instance.servers[*].public_ip ~}
    echo "${ip}" >> inventory
    %{ endfor ~}
    echo "server_hostname" >> inventory
    pip install ansible
  EOF
}
```

(Note that the above will generate a concatenation `>>` for even the first IP address, which is different from what you originally shared but I decided to keep it simple since the point of this example is only to show the template `for` syntax. Adjust as needed!)